# PHP import from CSV not overwriting old data with blanks

Tags: php, mysql, csv, import

if anyone can help that would be much appreciated, I've searched on here and google and can't find what's wrong, How do I say what the lines are terminated by? Heres the code..

```
 <?php if (isset($_POST['submitbulk'])) {
if (is_uploaded_file($_FILES['filename']['tmp_name'])) {
    echo "<h2>Orders Updated:</h2>";
    readfile($_FILES['filename']['tmp_name']);
}

//Import uploaded file to Database
$handle = fopen($_FILES['filename']['tmp_name'], "r");

while (($data = fgetcsv($handle, 1000, ",")) !== FALSE) {
    if ($data[2] != 0) {
    $shipdate = $data[2];
    }else{  
    $shipdate = date('Y-m-d');
    }
    if (isset($data[1])) {
        $vendor_invoice = $data[1];     
    }else{  
        $vendor_invoice = 0;     
    }
    if (isset($data[3])) {
        $shipping_cost = $data[3];     
    }else{  
        $shipping_cost = "";     
    }
    if (isset($data[4])) {
        $fedex_tracking = $data[4];    
        $fedex_notify_order[] = $data[0];
        $fedex_notify_tracking[] = $data[4];

    }else{  
        $fedex_trackoing = "";     
    }
    if (isset($data[5])) {
        $ups_tracking = $data[5]; 
        $ups_notify_order[] = $data[0];
        $ups_notify_tracking[] = $data[5];

    }else{  
        $ups_trackoing = "";     
    }
    if (isset($data[6])) {
        $ontrac_tracking = $data[6];  
        $ontrac_notify_order[] = $data[0];
        $ontrac_notify_tracking[] = $data[6];

    }else{  
        $ontrac_trackoing = "";     
    }   
    if (isset($fedex_tracking, $ups_tracking, $ontrac_tracking)) {
        $array3[] = $data[0];
    }else{
        echo "";
    }
$import = sprintf("UPDATE orders SET ".
                    "vendor_invoice_number='%s', ".
                    "ship_date='%s', ".
                    "ship_cost='%s', ".
                    "fedex_track_num='%s', ".
                    "ups_track_num='%s', ".
                    "ontrac_track_num='%s' ".
                  "WHERE orders_id=%s",

              mysql_real_escape_string($vendor_invoice), 
              mysql_real_escape_string($shipdate),
              mysql_real_escape_string($shipping_cost),
              mysql_real_escape_string($fedex_tracking),
              mysql_real_escape_string($ups_trackoing),
              mysql_real_escape_string($ontrac_tracking), 
              (int)$data[0]);
    mysql_query($import) or die(mysql_error());
}

fclose($handle);


    print "</br>Updated Successfully";

    //view upload form
}else { ?>

    Import Vendor Invoice Numbers<br />

    <form enctype='multipart/form-data' action='submit.php' method='post'>
    <input size='50' type='file' name='filename'><br />
    <input type='submit' name='submitbulk' value='Upload'></form>
 <?php   }
?>
```

The problem is that it is only importing the first line, I have tried ending the lines with /n /r/n, etc. but can't seem to find out whats going on. Any ideas on how to fix this?

Updated the code, it is now working just fine but it overwrites the data that's in the database when I don't want it. I thought that if I set it to "" it wouldn't change anything, but it is still changing it.. Any ideas on how to go about making it only update when there is something there?

Edit-
Would something like

```
$query = <<<eof
    LOAD DATA INFILE '$_FILES['filename']['tmp_name']'
     INTO TABLE orders
     FIELDS TERMINATED BY '|' OPTIONALLY ENCLOSED BY '"'
     LINES TERMINATED BY '\n'
    (orders_id,vendor_invoice_number,ship_date,ship_cost,fedex_track_num,ups_track_num,ontrac_track_num)
eof;
$db->query($query);
?>
```

work in a situation like this?

Comment: What about the file encoding? `fgetcsv` can only correctly read `utf-8`.

Comment: @iamsleepy This page is restricted by IP to people who know what to do, we don't have to worry about encoding, thankfully, but if there is a better way to do it I am all ears :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The way you construct your query is wrong. Your current code is a little confusing, I guess this is what you are looking for:

```
$import = sprintf("UPDATE orders SET ".
                    "vendor_invoice_number='%s', ".
                    "ship_date='%s', ".
                    "shipping_costs='%s', ".
                    "fedex_trackoing='%s', ".
                    "ups_trackoing='%s', ".
                    "ontrac_trackoing='%s' ".
                  "WHERE orders_id=%s",
                  mysql_real_escape_string($data[1]), 
                  mysql_real_escape_string($shipdate),
                  mysql_real_escape_string($shipping_cost),
                  mysql_real_escape_string($fedex_trackoing),
                  mysql_real_escape_string($ups_trackoing),
                  mysql_real_escape_string($ontrac_trackoing), 
                  (int)$data[0]);
```

The basic issue is that you try to use `'$data[1]'` *inside* a double quoted string initialization, which simply does not work.

But note that this is questionable. You should not blindly trust in data posted to your server. Anything can be in it and using such data the way you currently do opens huge security issues. Read a bit about "sql injection", think about switching to the advanced `mysqli` extension (the `mysql` extension you currently use is deprecated) and learn about the advantages of "prepared statements".

---

Update to account for the additional comment here / the updated question:

To prevent such an update query getting executed based on the contents of the csv file the easiest way would be to enclose either the execution command inside a conditional construct:

```
if (    ! empty($data[1])
     && ! empty($shipdate)
     && ! empty($shipping_cost) )
     && ! empty($fedex_trackoing) )
     && ! empty($ups_trackoing) )
     && ! empty($ontrac_trackoing) ) {
  mysql_query($import) or die(mysql_error());
}
```

Obviously the real condition you require depends on what exactly you want to judge as a situation where you decide *not* to update an existing entry in the database. When combining this with the original loop content posted inside the question it becomes clear that the code now is somewhat chaotic. It certainly would make sense to reimplement this is a more streamlined way...

Comment: Thanks, this worked, I know there are better ways to import the data but I wasn't able to get them to work, I was thikning of using parseCSV but I'm still trying to get it to work. Thankfully, we don't have to worry about sql injection because of who has access to the page.

Comment: Is there a way to make it only update the column if there is data in the csv file? I thought the if statement's setting it to "" would do that, but it is just changing it to blank

Comment: I edited my question to add another way I found, would something like this work?

Comment: Sure you can do that. This makes sense if you can use the data within the csv file in unaltered state. But typically one requires the flexibility of a scripting level sooner or later. Maybe for handling the data, but most likely for plausibility checks and validation steps.